# How to apply customisable texture colours in shader? (unity asset)

Tags: unity, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

I've extracted some assets from a unity game and so far managed to tweak most materials to my satisfaction.
However i can't figure out the customisable team colours of these 3d assets.
The default diffuse texture displays the model surface with a grey coating, while an additional ‘Team’ texture has a kind of RGB channelled filter for primary and secondary custom color, as well as parts of the texture that remain in default color (refer to image).
I figured it must be possible to customise in blender using nodes like ‘seperate RGB’, color ramps, rgb curves and mix shaders etc, but i’m not that familiar yet with all the ways these work together.
I’ve also included an image of what customisation looks like ingame.
[image: top left is the team texture, bottom left is the default diffuse.]

[image: ingame color coat, note that details remain]